# Object properties "blank" unless called specifically

Tags: javascript, logging, stringify

I have an object, let's say `current_group`. I am trying to print this object and it's contents to the screen so I can analyze it's properties (this is being pulled from an external system so I don't have docs on what to expect).

Anyways, I tried the following calls, and they resulted with just blank properties `ex. { id: '', status: '' }`

```
log.info(current_group);
log.info(JSON.stringify(current_group));
```

So, then I thought on a whim, I would try `log.info(current_group.id)` and it worked, it printed to the screen no issue and I didn't have to `stringify` it either.

Any idea what is happening here and how I can get the entire object contents to print in one call?

Comment: Something else must be changing the values of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to iterate through object:

```
var output = '';
for (let property in current_group) {
  output += property + ': ' + current_group[property]+'; ';
}
log.info(output);
```